# state.get is not a function when trying to map the react-redux State

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, immutable.js

Here I am trying to display the sources in my component but always i find error as `state.get` is not a function.

**reducer.js**

```
let initialState = Immutable.fromJS({sources: []});

export default function (state = initialState, action){
     switch(action.type){
         case GetSources:
             return state.merge({
                sources: action.sources
             });
        break;
     }
     return state;
}
```

**Component.js**

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
     return{
         sources: state.get('sources')
     }
}
```

**allReducers.js**

```
`const allReducers = combineReducers({
    sources:sources,
    news:news
})`
```

Comment: Do you use `combineReducers` somewhere?

Comment: Also what does the `state` object look like :S ?

Comment: My state object looks like: Object {sources: Map, news: Object}

Comment: i added the `combineReducers ` to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
     return{
         sources: state.sources.get('sources')
     }
}
```

Please note that state managed by given reducer is only part of the whole redux state if you use `combineReducers`. In such case to access slice of the state managed by given reducer you have to use key name at which given reducer was registered (in your case it's `sources`).
According to Redux `combineReducers` [docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html#combinereducersreducers), reducer returned by `combineReducers`:

> calls every child reducer, and gathers their
>   results into a single state object. The shape of the state object
>   matches the keys of the passed reducers

Comment: Great, I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it is because of the state persist in the local app state in chrome, and after I clean data site,  it works. I guess it is because of the state in my local is regular JS object and it needs to be removed first. otherwise it will convert the state back to regular JS object, even you combine it as immutable.